# Unhash Drupal 7 Users table Password

Tags: hash, drupal, passwords

I am looking for a mechanism for users table password field decryption or un-hash for Drupal 7. decryption is required for one of my project. this users table data need to be migrated in another system. any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not do reverse hashing, they are one way hashes. However if you want to migrate it to Drupal-8, there are ways to migrate users. But, thats only Drupal-7 to Drupal-8. Even then, you are not doing reverse hashing.

Answer (score 2):

As of Drupal 7, there is ***no way*** to decrypt user passwords ... full stop.

For more details, refer to the answers to [this question on Drupal.SE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/188542/39516).

Answer (score 1):

Concur with Pierre. Drupal 7 hashes are true hashes and therefore not 'reversible'. The original plaintexts must be known in order to verify them.

Your only other options are either:

- cracking them, or
- intercepting them at a low level as users successfully authenticate.

But both of these can be challenging (and even distasteful) in multiple ways, that are probably outside the scope of this question (as currently written):

- technically (How will you crack them, or how will you intercept?)
- security-wise (How can you keep the plaintexts safe? How will you destroy the plaintexts afterwards?)
- ethically (How can you do this without disclosing user passwords *to yourself*?)